# Kafka-Streams equivalent of table-valued function join or cross apply

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I'm working with a `KStream<key, coordinates>` I need to determine which perimeter each coordinate is within and output a `KStream<key, perimeterId>`.

All of the perimeters are within a `GlobalKTable<perimeterID, perimeterVertices>`.  I have a point-in-polygon function to do this, I just have no idea how to utilize it within Kafka-Streams without an obvious table-valued function or cross apply in Kafka-Streams.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing it an incredibly ugly way that may not be scalable.

My GlobalKTable is now a single row `"1"  List<perimeterID,perimeterVertices>`.
Which allows me to left join using "1" as my key for every event.  In the ValueJoiner I run my Point-in-Polygon function and set the perimeter ID then return a `<key, perimeterId>` to my output stream.

Comment: Would a GlobalKTable make sense here?

Comment: Ah, yes.  Apologies I actually used a GlobalKTable.  Updating my post.